# How to add an image in a specific area of the object in Cycles Render?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, texturing

I am trying to add an iris to the eye.[image]

I go to Object Data / Vertex Groups/ and I click in + . I select the area where I want to put the iris.
[image]

I go to texture/material and I add my iris. [image]
and Blender put the iris in the whole eye.[image]

I know I miss something but what?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/26865

Comment: What you are missing is **assigning** the material. See this post:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add different materials to different parts of a mesh?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Idle Chit-chat

Your title says "Cycles Render," but your screenshots are from *Blender Internal*. Also, in your last screenshot, you need to select *3D Viewport > Toolshelf > Edit > Shading: > Smooth* for the eye to not be pixelated in the viewport render.

However, if you are going for realism, I would suggest switching to Cycles Render (much faster, newer, better, AND built for photorealism). So, this tutorial is for Cycles. This will be the final result:

[image]

### Materials

I will use a sphere to represent the eye (smooth shading), and the following eye texture from [Google](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b7/Eye_I.jpg) (full size linked) in my demonstration.

[image]

With the sphere selected, go to the *Materials* tab in the *Properties panel*. *+ New* a material to the sphere. Go into the *Node editor*, and use the setup shown.

[image]

Now, go to the sphere in the *3D Viewport*. <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode, <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd> to front view, and <kbd>Numpad 5</kbd> to orthographic view. Enter *Face Select Mode*. Select these faces:

[image]

Press <kbd>U</kbd> and select *Project from View (Bounds)*. Split the screen into a *3D Viewport* and a *UV Image Editor* by dragging the marks in the top-right corner to the left. Make sure you are still in edit mode. Open the image of the eye through the toolbar at the bottom of the *UV Image Editor*. The orange should already be aligned over the eye.

### Final Notes

I added the nodes at the bottom to create red veins in the eye. It's more realistic.

Here is the finished .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Shady. You are right I took the screeshots in Blender Render.

Comment: @Meri You're welcome. Please consider accepting this answer if it helped you.

Comment: Hi @Shady please can you tell me where Multiply is in Note Editor? Thanks

Comment: Converter > Math. Don't forget to accept, please!

Comment: Sorry, yes I am going to accept. Thank you for your help. It is very useful.